# How to retrieve all records by foreign key with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to display all table records that match a foreign key id using Laravel. However, my query is not pulling any records into the view.

How do I find all of the records which match a foreign key id that is passed into the function?

**routes.php:**

```
Route::get('/personas/{idPersona}/quotes', 'QuoteController@index');
```

**QuoteController.php:**

```
public function index($id)
    {
        $quotes = Quote::where('idPersona', $id)->get();
        return View::make('quotes.index')->with('quotes', $quotes);
    }
```

**views/quotes/index.blade.php:**

```
<h2> Quotes </h2>

@foreach($quotes as $quote)

    <li>{{ $quote }}</li>

@endforeach
```

**models/Quote.php**

```
class Quote extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'quote';

    protected $primaryKey = 'idquote';

}
```

**models/Persona.php**

```
class Persona extends Eloquent {


    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'persona';

    protected $primaryKey = 'idPersona';


}
```

I have 2 tables, Persona and Quote, and I am trying to pull all the quotes that match the foreign key idPersona:

```
CREATE TABLE `mountain`.`persona` (
  `idPersona` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `lName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `mName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `bio` TEXT NULL,
  `dateBorn` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `dateDied` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPersona`));

CREATE TABLE `mountain`.`quote` (
  `idquote` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `quoteText` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `quoteSource1` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `quoteSource2` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `tag1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tag2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tag3` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `idPersona` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idquote`),
  INDEX `idPersona_idx` (`idPersona` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `idPersona`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPersona`)
    REFERENCES `mountain`.`persona` (`idPersona`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Comment: Note: `implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface` and `use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;` are needed only for a `User` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Eloquent, you have to get benifit of its powerfull ORM, to get all quotes that *belongs* to specific user you have to declare the relations first:

**models/Persona.php**

```
class Persona extends Eloquent {


    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'persona';

    protected $primaryKey = 'idPersona';

    function quotes() {
        return $this->hasMany('Quote', 'idquote');
    }

}
```

**models/Quote.php**

```
class Quote extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'quote';

    protected $primaryKey = 'idquote';

    function persona() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Persona', 'idPersona');
    }
}
```

Then you can simply get the desired `persona` with all related quotes by using the relation we difined above:

**QuoteController.php**

```
public function index($id) {
    $quotes = Persona::with('quotes')->find($id)->quotes;
    return View::make('quotes.index')->with('quotes', $quotes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to set up a Relationship between your Personas and your Quotes Model using Eloquent.

In your case you might want to apply a "hasMany/belongsTo" relationship as Quote->BelongsTo->Personas and a Personas has many Quotes?

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent gives you a more detailed overview over possible relationships.

Comment: If he will be using Eloquent, he will be using Quotes or Personas id. But if he will be using Fluent, then he can create a query to use the FK.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna use model relationships, you can simply use Database: Query Builder [for more details](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)

try this:

---

let's assume I have two tables:

**1. reports_has_tests**

**2.tests**. in tests table I have my foreign key.

```
 DB::table('reports_has_tests')
        ->join('tests', 'tests.id', '=', 'reports_has_tests.tests_id')
        ->select('tests.*')->where('reports_has_tests.reports_id',$yourID)->get();
```

---

Similarly with model you can do it like this:

```
 YourModelName::join('tests', 'tests.id', '=', 'reports_has_tests.tests_id')
            ->select('tests.*')->where('reports_has_tests.reports_id',$yourID)->get();
```

Note: I am adding this answer just to help those who don't want to use laravel models relationship and want to get the data directly from tables regarding single ID. In order to work with the above query, It is must that in your migrations/tables you have relationship.