# retrieve all records with laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I tried following the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) but didn't get the desired result,
My tables looks like

users table

```
id (pk - int) | username,
```

tweets table

```
id (pk - int) | user_id (fk - int) | tweet(varchar)
```

User Model

```
public function tweets() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Tweet', 'user_id); // user_id is FK
}
```

Tweet Model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

And on the controller side, I'am using eloquent to retrieve data. I have this method,

```
public function ajax($id) {
    $data = User::with('tweets')->find($id)->tweets();
    return $data;
}
```

I tried following the logic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108536/how-to-retrieve-all-records-by-foreign-key-with-laravel) but I'm getting the following error on the controller code:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Do a `dd(User::with('tweets')->find($id))`. This will, most likely return null, hence the error. You'll need to make sure the `$id` exists on the users table

Comment: Using `with()` eager loads the tweets. Unless you are explicitly looking to get the relationship back you should use `find($id)->tweets` rather than `tweets()` (note the lack of parentheses). The former gets the data and the latter gets the relationship.

Comment: Try `$data = User::with('tweets')->find($id)->tweets;` insteadof `$data = User::with('tweets')->find($id)->tweets();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply do like:

```
$User = User::find($id);
$tweets = Tweet::whereUserId($id)->get(); // or ->paginate(20);
return compact('User', 'tweets');
```

p.s. I know about eager loading, but it does the same operation + it also does additional but unnecessary operation to join `tweets` collection to `User` object.

Comment: can you please explain briefly how to use the method  whereUserId() ?

Comment: whereUserId($id) is same as where('user_id', $id) it's magic method in PHP that used by eloquent when You write whereSomethinElse($var) it converts to where('something_else', $var)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `->get();` to fetch all the records.